# Multiple dialog components in entryComponents error

Tags: angular, config, single-page-application, angular-material2

I have two separate dialog components (info, confirm).

They are both wired up in exactly the same manner.

app.shared.module.ts:

```
import { MatConfirmDialogComponent } from './somefolder/matconfirm-dialog.component';  
import { MatInfoDialogComponent } from './somefolder/matInfo-dialog.component'; 

declarations: [
        ..
        MatConfirmDialogComponent,
        MatInfoDialogComponent,
        ..
        entryComponents: [MatConfirmDialogComponent, MatInfoDialogComponent]
```

When I call both through the service the confirm one works fine, but I just cant get the Info dialog to work.

```
 openConfirmDialog(msg) {
        return this.dialog.open(MatConfirmDialogComponent,
            {
                width: '390px',
                disableClose: true,
                data: {
                    message: msg
                }
            });
    }

    openInfoDialog(msg) {
        this.dialog.open(MatInfoDialogComponent,
            {
                width: '390px',
                disableClose: true,
                data: {
                    message: msg
                }
            });
    }
```

It throws the Error:

```
No component factory found for t. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

Yes, I definitely did.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you exported them in the shared module?

Comment: Do you have only one module? Or you are importing that `app.shared.module.ts` in another module? In that case use `export: [MatConfirmDialogComponent, MatInfoDialogComponent]`

Comment: Tried exporting, no luck. The fact that one of them works perfectly fine is weird...

Comment: Are you calling both the dialogs from the same place and getting the error or the confirm dialog is called from some other place which is in a different module?

Comment: @Ritesh
Same place through the service call above.

Comment: Looks like it was a glitch just. I removed the second component. Built. Re-added it to the solution. Rebuilt. All working fine.

Comment: I am getting the same error can you help me what to do ?